# Why do android services run on the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

The page starts off by saying services are used to run long standing tasks in the background.  Later in the "caution:", it says they are run on the UI thread, and any intensive work should be done in a separate thread, like the code placed inside IntentService's "onHandleIntent" callback.

If the code in onHandleIntent is the service's long standing task, and that runs in a background thread, why do they say a service runs on the UI thread?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reasons for this:

1. UI thread is the way to work with events and binding, and is easier to understand how to interact with the service. That's usually already done on the UI thread, so it would also be easier to initiate functions on the service.
2. The service is a component without any UI, so it has less memory being used compared to activities, and also has less chance of having memory leaks compared to activities.
3. The service can run in the foreground, making it have less chance of being killed when the user goes to other apps.
4. there is also an [**IntentService**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), which has a function (called "[**onHandleIntent**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent))" )that runs only on the background thread, if you wish to perform easy background tasks easily.
5. Instead of forcing you to work in some way, Google lets you decide how&what to perform on the service.
6. It has its own lifecycle that isn't affected by UI. It's more affected by resource usage and OS decisions, and by the developer's choice of course.